# NODE JS error :con.query(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
function liveFeed_update() {
  //var num_row = 0;
  var _scripPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var query_01 = "SELECT count (*) as total  FROM livedata where 
    script_name = 'ABC'
    ";  
    con.query(query_01).then(function(response) {
        resolve(response);
        console.log(response); //end of resolve
      }) //end of then
      .catch(function(error) {
        reject(error);
        console.log(error);

      }) //end of catch
  });

  _scripPromise.then(function(message) {
      console.log(message);
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

Please help me to fix this error.

I am getting this:

```
"TypeError: con.query(...).then is not a function"
```

Comment: Where is `con` coming from? Add rest of the code

Comment: What is `con`? Why do you think its `query` method returns a promise?

Comment: Don't nest promises: https://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/

Comment: con is used for sql connection

Comment: var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "table"
});

Comment: And what is `mysql`? There are a number of MySQL libraries on NPM.

Comment: Please add relevant code for this post